# What is the best UI element dragging algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I made a GUI application but I am stuck with a workaround algorithm to drag/move ui element relatively to another surface (screen, canvas, etc.). In my case I use it for a window relative to the screen, but that's beside the point because this algorithm should work anywhere possible. Here is my algorithm:

**code-listing-1.**

```
MouseMotionAdapter(){
            int prevX = -1000, prevY = -1000, getX, getY;
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
              //if initial cursor position isn't set 
                if(prevX==-1000){
                    prevX = e.getLocationOnScreen().x;
                    prevY = e.getLocationOnScreen().y;
                    getX = e.getX();
                    getY = e.getY();
                }
               //move element to new position 
                theFrame.setBounds(theFrame.getBounds().x+e.getX()-getX, theFrame.getBounds().y+e.getY()-getY, 880, 583);
                prevX=e.getLocationOnScreen().x;
                prevY=e.getLocationOnScreen().y;
            }
```

The trouble with this algorithm is that the mouse cursor position is definitely fixed relatively to the element and if I try to move/drag the element clicking in another position/part of the element the whole element moves so that the mouse cursor is positioned at the "initial position", which is not the behaviour I want (I want it to have the behaviour we mostly know like when we move an icon on desktop or a window on the screen, etc.)

Can anyone help with that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be setting the initial position in the `mouseDown` method.

Comment: Some tips - (1) That "The trouble with" paragraph is a bit difficult to understand - it might be helpful to include some actual coordinates and screenshots in your explanation. (but user3386109 is probably right about the problem) (2) You should always try to debug your code prior to asking a [so] question. While debugging code regarding mouse events is admittedly difficult, it's not that difficult to insert a few print statements showing what executes when and how the variables change.

Comment: An actual [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would involve less guess work and better responses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual approach in such a case is to compute the difference between the current and the previous position. This difference is then "the movement", that is added to the position of the dragged object.

(BTW: You seem to not use the `prev...` values in your computation at all!)

Inside a `MouseMotionListener`, this could roughly look as follows:

```
class MouseDraggingControl implements MouseMotionListener 
{
    private Point previousPoint = new Point();

    @Override 
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
        previousPoint = e.getPoint();
    }

    @Override 
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
        int movementX = e.getX() - previousPoint.x;
        int movementY = e.getY() - previousPoint.y;

        doMovement(movementX, movementY);

        previousPoint = e.getPoint();
    }
}
```

In your case, the `doMovement` method might be implemented like this:

```
private void doMovement(int movementX, int movementY)
{
    int oldX = theFrame.getX();
    int oldY = theFrame.getY();
    int newX = oldX + movementX;
    int newY = oldY + movementY;
    theFrame.setLocation(newX, newY);
}
```

(or similar, using the `getBounds`/`setBounds` calls)

---

**EDIT** If the mouse motion listener is attached directly to the component that should be dragged, you might have to use the "location on screen" instead:

```
class MouseDraggingControl implements MouseMotionListener 
{
    private Point previousPoint = new Point();

    @Override 
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
        previousPoint = e.getLocationOnScreen();
    }

    @Override 
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
        Point p = e.getLocationOnScreen();
        int movementX = p.x - previousPoint.x;
        int movementY = p.y - previousPoint.y;

        doMovement(movementX, movementY);

        previousPoint = e.getLocationOnScreen();
    }
}
```

If this does not solve your issue, I'd like to emphasize the comment from MadProgrammer: An example that demonstrates your *actual* problem would help here.

Comment: the window is shaking when I use this algorithm

Comment: @PaikuHan Added an **EDIT** - if this does not help, you may have to describe your current setup in more detail.

Comment: Just to be sure (since it works). the reason behind all the shaking bug was that I actually set the bounds of the dragged element relative to a location of the mouse that wasn't the surface in which I was trying to drag the element (i.e. taking mouse location on a surface A to move the dragged element on a surface B different to A while the element is on B and not A) I am right?

Comment: I did not understand the details of your question (A, B, what?) - but to put it simply: When a "mouseDragged" event occurs, and the component *on* which this event happened is then moved, subsequent events will refer to the coordinates of the mouse based on the *new* position of the component. This causes inconsistent results when computing the difference to the *old* position, because the *old* position still refers to the *old* position of the dragged component. I can try to add a sketch if this does not answer the question.

Comment: I do understand the algorithm (and to tell the truth my first attempt to move a component was something like what you did here without the doMovement() of course but since the component was shaking I had find a workaround). By surface I meant component (surface is an SDL structure with a width and a height which can be used to make a 2d component from scratch). My question was, was it shaking because I took the mouse location from a wrong component/point of view?

Comment: @PaikuHan Admittedly, I can hardly say for sure what caused the problem originally (I don't have a runnable example to test this). But the "shaking" indicates that you took the wrong coordinates, probably from the component *before* and *after* it was moved.